Google Wallet Pass Logo Update
My users can download individualized Google wallet (private) passes. Users belong to different groups, and based on what group they are in will determine the logo on the pass. If the user's group does not have a specified logo, a generic one is used. I have a tool to upload a new logo for a group, which saves the uploaded .png to an S3 bucket. I then have to reach out to Google to get them to allow/authorize the S3 URL in which the image is stored.
This all works fine. An issue I have run into now is if a group with an already existing logo desires a new one. I upload the new logo (the S3 URL remains the same, as that is the way I have set up the code), but when I download the pass, the old logo still appears. I know the new logo has been uploaded correctly because when I download the same "pass", but for ios/apple, the new logo is displayed.
Does Google somehow cache the image/url I sent them, and even though a new image has been uploaded, the pass gets the cached version? What could be causing this?
Is there something I need to do to get the pass(es) to register the new image (even though its the identical URL)?
